# org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPException: cannot create cipher: No such algorithm: RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding

Tags: java, linux, encryption, bouncycastle, pgp

Forgive my ignorance with encryption.  I am attempting to use Bouncy Castle's PGP encryption.  I was able to use the examples packaged with the jar to create a nice working solution (I thought).  All was well, I was able to use my public key to encrypt and my private key to decrypt for testing purposes.  The issue arose when I pushed my changes to a linux server.  Once the changes were on the linux server my decript method threw 'org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPException: cannot create cipher: No such algorithm: RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding'

I found this incredibly odd as I had no problem locally.  I went about printing all of the Security.getProviders() and their algorithms to see if I could determine the difference between the remote and local environment.  Sure enough, my local environment had an entry for 'RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding' while the remote environment did not.  After a lot of google searching it became apparent that the JRE jar that was providing the 'RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding' algorithm (sunMSCAPI.jar) is windows only and not packaged with the jre for linux, as far as I can tell.
Here is my pom.xml for bouncy castle:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcpg-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.56</version>
</dependency>
```

Server Java Information:

java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)

Linux Version:
command: cat /etc/issue.net | head -1

Oracle Linux Server release 6.8

Another important note is that it only throws that exception for GPG v2 and not for GPG v1.49.  I only noticed this because I was given the public key for our integration partner and in the public key .asc it says 'Version: GnuPG v1.4.9 (AIX)'

I'm slowly slipping into madness as I search forums for a solution.  I would really like to know why 'RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding' is not an available algorithm on my linux server and where I should go next for a solution.

As requested here is the code snippet of the offending code:

```
byte[] bytes = compressFile(tempFile.getAbsolutePath(), CompressionAlgorithmTags.ZIP);

        PGPEncryptedDataGenerator encGen = new PGPEncryptedDataGenerator(
                new JcePGPDataEncryptorBuilder(PGPEncryptedData.CAST5).setWithIntegrityPacket(true)
                        .setSecureRandom(new SecureRandom()).setProvider("BC"));

        encGen.addMethod(new JcePublicKeyKeyEncryptionMethodGenerator(encKey).setProvider("BC"));

        OutputStream tempFileOutputStream = new ArmoredOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(tempFile));

        // This cOut OutputStream is an instance of WrappedGeneratorStream
        // (Bouncy Castle Class)
        // The below code is the offending code
        OutputStream cOut = encGen.open(tempFileOutputStream, bytes.length);
```

The PGPEncryptedDataGenerator class is a BouncyCastle class.

Comment: You need to provide more information. For example, what version of Java is on the Linux server?

Comment: Sorry about that, probably good information to have.  I have updated the question with the java and linux versions of the server.

Comment: You could also provide the code snippet that's causing the error. Is it a bouncycastle class or `java.security` ones?

Comment: I included the code snippet. The class being called is a BouncyCastle class.  You can pull up the exact source for that class via the BouncyCastle documentation.